# ¿Como puedo vaciar varias tablas con un sola secuencia?

Tags: mysql

Hola tengo un botón por la cual dice "eliminar todo", y me gustaría que al dar click me vacíe varías tablas que hay, me informé que esto: `$sql = "truncate tabla1,tabla2,tabla3,etc";` no es posible, así que ví una respuesta que no entendí que decía que se podía hacer:

```
truncate table1;
go
truncate table2;
go
truncate table3;
...
```

Y si es cierto como sería? Sería así?

```
$sql ="
truncate table1;
go
truncate table2;
go
truncate table3;
";
```

y si no se puede así hay otro solución?

Comment: Podrías llamar a un stored procedure, esa seria otra solucion, pero con el go deberia funcionarte.

Comment: Así como he puesto en el ejemplo no me funcionó.

Comment: Y si pones el codigo directo en SQL si funciona? qu error te marca en programacion?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con un arreglo

```
$truncate = array( 'tabla1', 'tabla2', 'tabla3' );

foreach( $truncate as $table ){
  $sql = "truncate " . $table;
  mysqli_query( $tuConexion, $sql );
}
```

Yo utilicé `mysqli_query`, pero tu puedes ponerlo a como estás usandolo

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré otra solución, como no encontré una solución para vaciar varias tablas con una secuencia en MySQL, lo que hice es meter todas las llamadas AJAX en un AJAX.
así:

```
        var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"eliminar_todo_vacaciones_navidad.php",
      data:fecha,
      success:function(x){
        if (x==1) {
          var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"eliminar_todo_inicio_curso1.php",
            data:fecha,
            success:function(y){
              if (y==1) {
                var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url:"eliminar_todo_vacaciones_pascua.php",
                  data:fecha,
                  success:function(z){
                    if (z==1) {
                      var fecha = $("#form_fecha").serialize();
                      $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"eliminar_todo_dias_festivos.php",
                        data:fecha,
                        success:function(){

                        }
                      });
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }).done(function(){
        $("#correcto_eliminar").animate({
          top:"2%"
        },500);
        $("#correcto_eliminar").delay(1000);
        $("#correcto_eliminar").animate({
          top:"-15%"
        },500);
    }).fail(function(){
        $("#error_eliminar").animate({
          top:"2%"
        },500);
        $("#error_eliminar").delay(1000);
        $("#error_eliminar").animate({
          top:"-15%"
        },500); 
    });
```

Lógicamente. Y me funcionó además lógicamente si alguna petición AJAX me falla me mostrará lo que he puesto en fail() y si todas son correctas, me hará lo que haiga en el done().

**Gracias por vuestro interés.**

Comment: Me gusta más la solución de [Alberto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178477/21), sea como sea, en StackOverflow, la idea es que marques alguna solución como aceptada, y esa puede ser esta respuesta tuya, si con eso resolviste el problema. Te animo a hacerlo. Un saludo.